# Google Tag Manager equivalent of adding multiple IDs with gtag( 'config' )

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been working on a migration from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4, and am considering switching to Google Tag Manager at the same time. I'm trying to make sure the initial code on the site will work correctly.

Here's what we previously used with Analytics:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=[analytics id]"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag( 'js', new Date() );
gtag( 'config', '[analytics id]', {"optimize_id":"[optimize id]"} );
gtag( 'config', '[ads id]' ); // this is a different ID than the Analytics one
</script>
```

The Google Tag Manager looks like this:

```
<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.'+'js?id='+i+dl+'&gtm_auth=[environment auth code]&gtm_preview=[environment id]&gtm_cookies_win=x';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','[tag manager id]');
</script>
```

On the Analytics code, I'm able to supply an ID for (universal) Analytics and Google Ads by using the `config` method. On the new Tag Manager code, there appears to only be one Google Tag Manager ID.

I'm aware that I can add things like Google Analytics 4, Universal Analytics, Google Ads Remarketing, Google Ads Conversion, etc. as distinct Tags with their own ids within Google Tag Manager. But is there an equivalent to this initial `config` method? Or is that something that Tag Manager takes care of on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTM takes care of it. Every tag type will load its respective library if it's not yet loaded (it's best to let GTM load its stuff as needed), then execute the config method if it's applicable to the library/tag type and fire events as needed.

GTM will also define dataLayer if it's not defined. It will also hijack the dataLayer from gtag, so no need defining the gtag() function. Basically, pretty much anything you can do with gtag in code is better done through GTM, so if you do tracking properly through GTM, you don't even touch gtag.

dataLayer, in GTM world, becomes a tool of communication between front-end and GTM's logic rather than just direct mindless proxy to GA endpoints, as gtag() offers it.

Useful for GA4 double tracking into different measurement ids, Killan Walsh in Measure slack just uncovered it. You can supply comma-separated measurement ids in the GA4 config tag like so:

[image]

Just return comma-separated measurement ids in a string from that var. But this seems like an undocumented, unfinished feature, so use with caution.

Comment: Thank you. To make sure I'm clear, does that mean that there's no GTM equivalent to having two different `config` calls because GTM will take care of that data transfer, as well as whatever libraries it needs to load?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you still can do two config calls through GTM, but in a different context. Say, if you want to send GA4 events to two measurement ids. Some sites do that. In that case, you would either have two config tags, or just set two comma-separated measurement ids in on config tag. Will add a screenshot for that. But it's not your case since you're gonna be using two different types of tags anyhow. They will do all necessary config calls for you.

Comment: This is super helpful. So I could either: 1) add the Analytics ID and the Google Ads ID separated by a comma in the measurement ID of a single GA4 Configuration Tag, OR I could add both as separate GA4 Configuration Tags.

It does seem like using the comma is more similar to what we are doing now with two `config` calls, but if it's not necessarily supported that does seem riskier.

Comment: Yes, don't use comma-separated for now. I think it's undocumented yet. Even though gtag is an old library, all the GA4 stuff is still really just a bug-infested beta in active development.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a GTM container where I want to fire two Measurement ID's simultaneously in a GA4 Config Tag. Using the comma to separate the ID's worked but then my website backoffice went down due to _ga G-XXX, G-XXX cookie. I investigate this issue and it seems that web browsers don't recommend commas in cookie names.

Comment: That's good to know. Just make a separate set of tags. GA4 in GTM is underdeveloped, so yes, some wasteful duplication is due. But it's easier if you keep your GA4 tags to minimum, having them rather universal.