# Can I send GA4 events from one website to two different GA4 measurement IDs with a lookup table?

Tags: google-tag-manager, lookup-tables

So, I have a GTM container installed on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I want to send the same events to two different GA4 properties (GTM-XXXXXXXXXX and GTM-YYYYYYYYYY). I can't modify the site's code so that's why I have to do this using GTM.

I thought about using a lookup table like this but it's only sending the data to the second GA4 ID(GTM-YYYYYYYYYY):

[GTM lookup table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocTdz.png)

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Look up tables are useless if you expect your input to stay the same.

Check out this answer: [Google Tag Manager equivalent of adding multiple IDs with gtag( 'config' )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540062/google-tag-manager-equivalent-of-adding-multiple-ids-with-gtag-config)

In short: GA4 is still raw, including its implementation in GTM. For now, we're forced to duplicate GA4 tags if we want to send them to different measurement ids. There are more elegant solutions, but they're buggy.

Comment: I actually found a way, curious what you think about it:

I modified the lookup table so there's only one input and I set the output as a variable that contains an array, this array contains the two measurement IDs and so far it's sending the event to both ga4 properties with very minimal variation.

Comment: yeah, you don't need a look up table for that. You can do it as a constant. Read the answer in the link I gave and read the comments. It's buggy.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Yeah, the data is not matching so I'm just going to have to bite the bullet and create another set of events. The comma-separated thing looked promising but some dude said that it broke the site so I wouldn't want to work with that.